# Rigorous definition of an embedded connected sum.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Can someone point me to a rigorous definition of a connected sum of two *smooth* embeddings? I know about the usual construction, the problem is that I can't find a proof that this construction is well defined.

Say, we have two smooth embeddings $f:M\rightarrow{\mathbb R}^n$ and $g:N\rightarrow{\mathbb R}^n$. I need to construct a *smooth* embedding $f\#g:M\# N\rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$.

Usually you just connect $f(M)$ and $g(N)$ with a tube along an arc and then smooth the result. I know why the result does not depend on the choice of an arc in codimension at least 3. But why does it not depend on the smoothing procedure?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Independence of the smoothing operation is the same thing as well-definedness of connected sum of smooth manifolds. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think it is not the same thing.

Comment: I think it is not the same thing. Well-definedness of connected sum of smooth manifolds implies that no matter how we smooth we will get an embedding of $M\# N$. But why are all this different embeddings smoothly isotopic?

Comment: When you take two neighborhoods in $M$ and $N$, they must be diffeomorphic to standard $S^m$, so the tube will be diffeomorphic to $I\times S^m$. Therefore as partially-smooth manifolds two different connected sums will be isomorphic; but I don't know why therefore their smoothing will be.

Comment: When you consider a connected sum of two smooth manifolds you want to obtain a smooth (not piecewise-smooth) manifold as a result. So, you nned too "smooth" corners, where the tube meets the manifolds. It can me done and the connected sum is actually well defined. I.e., if you use a different tube or smooth in a different way you will still get a diffeomorphic manifold.

However, my original question is about the connected sum of *embeddings*, not manifolds.